# How to show text for 5 seconds then disappear and display buttons?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-clock

I am trying to make it so when you get an answer correct in my trivia game, it will get rid of the big question you see and say "well done" for 5 seconds and then go back to the main menu where there are 4 randomly selected questions. The questions are loaded in from a quizfile.csv and contains:

```
What colour is elon musk's hair?,brown
What is most popular sport?,football
What was Queen first called?,Smile
What's superior Apple Or Windows?,Windows
```

They are random as they are just placeholder and for testing purposes only.
The place where I want the pause/display for 5  seconds function is on line 115 of the first file.

I have tried `time.sleep(5)` and this just freezes the program and doesn't display it for 5 seconds, much like for less than a second. Would I need to use `pygame.event.set_timer()` and if so, how?

```
import csv
import sys
import random
import pygame
import textwrap
import time
import pygame_textinput
textinput = pygame_textinput.TextInput()


pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS=60
SCREENSIZE = SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT = 1080, 720
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREENSIZE)

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
yellow = (255, 255, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)

questions = {}

def wrap_text(message, wraplimit): #keep text on screen
    return textwrap.fill(message, wraplimit)

def text_objects(text,font): #render text
    textSurf = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurf, textSurf.get_rect()


def question(text):
    xx=0
    text = wrap_text(text,20) #wrap text
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',100)
    for part in text.split('\n'): #for each line from the wrapped text
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(part, largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((SCREENWIDTH/2)),(SCREENHEIGHT/2+xx)
        screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
        xx+=75 #change height of text so doesnt overlap



class Button:
    def __init__(self, question, answer,positionx,positiony): #setup all vars
        self.question = question
        self.answer = answer
        self.positionx = positionx
        self.positiony = positiony

    def button(self):
        ltr = len(self.question)
        w= 12.5*ltr #make width of button big enough for text
        button = pygame.Rect(self.positionx,self.positiony,w,50) #make button
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',20)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(self.question, largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((self.positionx+(w/2)),(self.positiony+25)) #button text
        return button, TextSurf, TextRect
    def question(self):
        question(self.question) #display question
    def giveQuestionAnswer(self):
        return self.question,self.answer #give question and answer

with open("quizfile.csv") as f: #load in questions
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    quiz_qas = list(reader) 

z=0 #for positioning
t=0 #for loop
quiz = random.sample(quiz_qas, 4) #randomly select 4 questions
for q, a in quiz: #for every question and answer in the file
    questions[q] = a #define the dictionary of questions and answers
    for x, y in questions.items(): #for every answer and question in the dictionary, link them
        if t==0: #the sweet spots for getting a different question every time
            b = Button(x,y,200,200) #make button object
            z+=50

        elif t==5:
            b1 = Button(x,y,600,200)
            z+=50

        elif t==7:
            b2 = Button(x,y,600,400)
            z+=50
        elif t==9:
            b3 = Button(x,y,200,400)
            z+=50
        t+=1

b2on = False #for handling displaying the question
b3on = False
b4on = False
b5on = False
correct=False
gameState = "running"  # controls which state the games is in
# game loop #################### runs 60 times a second!
while gameState != "exit":  # game loop - note:  everything in the mainloop is indented one tab

    screen.fill(white)
    events = pygame.event.get()
    if b2on:
        q,a = b.giveQuestionAnswer() #get question and answer
        question(q) #display answer
        # Feed it with events every frame
        # Blit its surface onto the screen
        screen.blit(textinput.get_surface(), (10, 10))
        if textinput.update(events): #if hit enter
            if textinput.get_text() == a:
                b2on = False
                correct=True

    if correct:
        question("well done")
        #PAUSE SCREEN HERE AND DISPLAY WELL DONE FOR 5 SECONDS
        correct=False

    elif b3on:
        q,a = b1.giveQuestionAnswer()
        question(q)

        textinput.update(events)
        screen.blit(textinput.get_surface(), (10, 10))
        if textinput.update(events): #if hit enter
            if textinput.get_text() == a:
                b3on = False
                correct=True

    elif b4on:
        q,a = b2.giveQuestionAnswer()
        question(q)

        textinput.update(events)
        screen.blit(textinput.get_surface(), (10, 10))
        if textinput.update(events): #if hit enter
            if textinput.get_text() == a:
                b4on = False
                correct=True

    elif b5on:
        q,a = b3.giveQuestionAnswer()
        question(q)

        textinput.update(events)
        screen.blit(textinput.get_surface(), (10, 10))
        if textinput.update(events): #if hit enter
            if textinput.get_text() == a:
                b5on = False
                correct=True

    elif b2on==False and b3on==False and b4on==False and b5on==False:
        B2,TextSurf,TextRect = b.button() #draw buttons
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, [255, 0, 0], B2)
        screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        B3,TextSurf,TextRect = b1.button()
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, [255, 0, 0], B3)
        screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        B4,TextSurf,TextRect = b2.button()
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, [255, 0, 0], B4)
        screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        B5,TextSurf,TextRect = b3.button()
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, [255, 0, 0], B5)
        screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)


    for event in pygame.event.get():  # get user interaction events
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # tests if window's X (close) has been clicked
            gameState = "exit"  # causes exit of game loop
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_pos = event.pos  # gets mouse position

            if B2.collidepoint(mouse_pos): #if click on button
                b2on = True #display question
            if B3.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                b3on = True
            if B4.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                b4on = True
            if B5.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                b5on = True


    pygame.display.update()            
    pygame.display.flip()  # transfers build screen to human visable screen
    clock.tick(FPS)  # limits game to frame per second, FPS value

# out of game loop ###############
print("The game has closed") 
pygame.quit() 
sys.exit()
```

and here is the pygame_textinput.py file I am using to create that blinking input effect and function.

```
"""
Copyright 2017, Silas Gyger, silasgyger@gmail.com, All rights reserved.

Borrowed from https://github.com/Nearoo/pygame-text-input under the MIT license.
"""

import os.path

import pygame
import pygame.locals as pl

pygame.font.init()


class TextInput:
    """
    This class lets the user input a piece of text, e.g. a name or a message.
    This class let's the user input a short, one-lines piece of text at a blinking cursor
    that can be moved using the arrow-keys. Delete, home and end work as well.
    """
    def __init__(
            self,
            initial_string="",
            font_family="",
            font_size=35,
            antialias=True,
            text_color=(0, 0, 0),
            cursor_color=(0, 0, 1),
            repeat_keys_initial_ms=400,
            repeat_keys_interval_ms=35):
        """
        :param initial_string: Initial text to be displayed
        :param font_family: name or list of names for font (see pygame.font.match_font for precise format)
        :param font_size:  Size of font in pixels
        :param antialias: Determines if antialias is applied to font (uses more processing power)
        :param text_color: Color of text (duh)
        :param cursor_color: Color of cursor
        :param repeat_keys_initial_ms: Time in ms before keys are repeated when held
        :param repeat_keys_interval_ms: Interval between key press repetition when helpd
        """

        # Text related vars:
        self.antialias = antialias
        self.text_color = text_color
        self.font_size = font_size
        self.input_string = initial_string  # Inputted text

        if not os.path.isfile(font_family):
            font_family = pygame.font.match_font(font_family)

        self.font_object = pygame.font.Font(font_family, font_size)

        # Text-surface will be created during the first update call:
        self.surface = pygame.Surface((1, 1))
        self.surface.set_alpha(0)

        # Vars to make keydowns repeat after user pressed a key for some time:
        self.keyrepeat_counters = {}  # {event.key: (counter_int, event.unicode)} (look for "***")
        self.keyrepeat_intial_interval_ms = repeat_keys_initial_ms
        self.keyrepeat_interval_ms = repeat_keys_interval_ms

        # Things cursor:
        self.cursor_surface = pygame.Surface((int(self.font_size/20+1), self.font_size))
        self.cursor_surface.fill(cursor_color)
        self.cursor_position = len(initial_string)  # Inside text
        self.cursor_visible = True  # Switches every self.cursor_switch_ms ms
        self.cursor_switch_ms = 500  # /|\
        self.cursor_ms_counter = 0

        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    def update(self, events):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self.cursor_visible = True  # So the user sees where he writes

                # If none exist, create counter for that key:
                if event.key not in self.keyrepeat_counters:
                    self.keyrepeat_counters[event.key] = [0, event.unicode]

                if event.key == pl.K_BACKSPACE:
                    self.input_string = (
                        self.input_string[:max(self.cursor_position - 1, 0)]
                        + self.input_string[self.cursor_position:]
                    )

                    # Subtract one from cursor_pos, but do not go below zero:
                    self.cursor_position = max(self.cursor_position - 1, 0)
                elif event.key == pl.K_DELETE:
                    self.input_string = (
                        self.input_string[:self.cursor_position]
                        + self.input_string[self.cursor_position + 1:]
                    )

                elif event.key == pl.K_RETURN:
                    return True

                elif event.key == pl.K_RIGHT:
                    # Add one to cursor_pos, but do not exceed len(input_string)
                    self.cursor_position = min(self.cursor_position + 1, len(self.input_string))

                elif event.key == pl.K_LEFT:
                    # Subtract one from cursor_pos, but do not go below zero:
                    self.cursor_position = max(self.cursor_position - 1, 0)

                elif event.key == pl.K_END:
                    self.cursor_position = len(self.input_string)

                elif event.key == pl.K_HOME:
                    self.cursor_position = 0

                else:
                    # If no special key is pressed, add unicode of key to input_string
                    self.input_string = (
                        self.input_string[:self.cursor_position]
                        + event.unicode
                        + self.input_string[self.cursor_position:]
                    )
                    self.cursor_position += len(event.unicode)  # Some are empty, e.g. K_UP

            elif event.type == pl.KEYUP:
                # *** Because KEYUP doesn't include event.unicode, this dict is stored in such a weird way
                if event.key in self.keyrepeat_counters:
                    del self.keyrepeat_counters[event.key]

        # Update key counters:
        for key in self.keyrepeat_counters:
            self.keyrepeat_counters[key][0] += self.clock.get_time()  # Update clock

            # Generate new key events if enough time has passed:
            if self.keyrepeat_counters[key][0] >= self.keyrepeat_intial_interval_ms:
                self.keyrepeat_counters[key][0] = (
                    self.keyrepeat_intial_interval_ms
                    - self.keyrepeat_interval_ms
                )

                event_key, event_unicode = key, self.keyrepeat_counters[key][1]
                pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(pl.KEYDOWN, key=event_key, unicode=event_unicode))

        # Re-render text surface:
        self.surface = self.font_object.render(self.input_string, self.antialias, self.text_color)

        # Update self.cursor_visible
        self.cursor_ms_counter += self.clock.get_time()
        if self.cursor_ms_counter >= self.cursor_switch_ms:
            self.cursor_ms_counter %= self.cursor_switch_ms
            self.cursor_visible = not self.cursor_visible

        if self.cursor_visible:
            cursor_y_pos = self.font_object.size(self.input_string[:self.cursor_position])[0]
            # Without this, the cursor is invisible when self.cursor_position > 0:
            if self.cursor_position > 0:
                cursor_y_pos -= self.cursor_surface.get_width()
            self.surface.blit(self.cursor_surface, (cursor_y_pos, 0))

        self.clock.tick()
        return False

    def get_surface(self):
        return self.surface

    def get_text(self):
        return self.input_string

    def get_cursor_position(self):
        return self.cursor_position

    def set_text_color(self, color):
        self.text_color = color

    def set_cursor_color(self, color):
        self.cursor_surface.fill(color)

    def clear_text(self):
        self.input_string = ""
        self.cursor_position = 0
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to use a timer event. See [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html).

Create a user event and a `paused` state.

```py
pausetimerevent = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
paused = False
```

If the game is paused then display "well done". When the answer is correct, then set `paused = True` and start the timer. See [`pygame.time.set_timer`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer):

```py
while gameState != "exit": 

    if not paused and b2on:
        # [...]


    if paused:
        question("well done")

    elif correct:
        correct = False
        paused = True
        pygame.time.set_timer(pausetimerevent, 5000) # 5000 milliseconds = 5 socond
```

After the the time has elapsed, the event occurs. Reset `paused` and reset the timer by passing 0 to the time argument:

```py
while gameState != "exit": 

    # [...]

    for event in pygame.event.get():  # get user interaction events
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # tests if window's X (close) has been clicked
            gameState = "exit"  # causes exit of game loop
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_pos = event.pos  # gets mouse position

            # [...]

        if event.type == pausetimerevent:
            pygame.time.set_timer(pausetimerevent, 0) # stop timer
            paused = False
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use pygame.time.wait() or pygame.time.delay() [they are different, try both]. In theory it should work ;)

Edit:
If you want to run your loop while the text is displaying you could make a variable called something like "welldonetime" and when you want to display the well done text you could assign it to 5000 milliseconds, then call

```
continue
```

which basically skips current loop cycle
. Afterwards you would add an if statement at the top of your loop that checks if the "welldonetime" variable is greater that 0 if so display well done text, and subtract elapsed time from "welldonetime".
once "welldonetime" goes back to 0 it would do the rest of stuff in your loop

```py
b2on = False #for handling displaying the question
b3on = False
b4on = False
b5on = False
correct=False
gameState = "running"  # controls which state the games is in

#edited here:
displaywelldoneuntil = 0
#end of edited

# game loop #################### runs 60 times a second!
while gameState != "exit":  # game loop - note:  everything in the mainloop is indented one tab

    screen.fill(white)
    events = pygame.event.get()

    #edited here too:
    if pygame.time.get_ticks() < displaywelldoneuntil:
        question("well done")
        continue #skip the rest of the current loop iteration
    #end of edited

    if b2on:
        q,a = b.giveQuestionAnswer() #get question and answer
        question(q) #display answer
        # Feed it with events every frame
        # Blit its surface onto the screen
        screen.blit(textinput.get_surface(), (10, 10))
        if textinput.update(events): #if hit enter
            if textinput.get_text() == a:
                b2on = False
                correct=True

    #edited here:
    if correct:
        displaywelldoneuntil = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 5000 # display well done until current time plus 5000ms 
        correct=False
        continue #skip the rest of the current loop iteration
    #end of edited

    elif b3on:
```

Here you go, I think this is the most straightforward way although Rabbid76's answer is slightly more elegant ;)

Comment: would this freeze the game, e.g stopping the loop momentarily?

Comment: ah this is what the other ones I have tried have done, could you try running my code with your method put in and test it for me as I do not have access to a computer atm. If it works, it should say "well done" for a few seconds

Comment: how would I incorporate your edited version into mine, would you be able to give an example? I am struggling to understand sorry

Comment: did you try pygame.time.wait and pygame.time.delay ? did it work?

Comment: This does not work, it freezes the screen on the question instead of freezing on well done